# How to make user's input then a variable?

Tags: batch-file

How I make the user's input a variable? (I have no idea asking this because I'm working on a setup...)

For example, if the user's input would be "input" could I make a variable that is the user's input? If the user's input is "3" the variable would be 3. If the input of the user (or answer) would be 4 then the variable would be 4.

Code:

```
:loop
set /p input=input something here: 
if %input%==. goto loop
if not %input%==. goto store_userinput_as_variable
:store_userinput_as_variable
cls
echo Your input has been stored in a variable.
```

But how i make a variable that is what the user inputed? Please help!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Whatever the user enters for _input something here:_ will be stored in the `%input%` variable. Are you asking that if they enter "MyValue" then a new variable named `%MyValue%` will be created?

Comment: Thanks Jason Faulkner. ;). That user's input is actually %input%. Although i ignore the text "Are you asking that if they enter "MyValue" then a new variable named %MyValue% will be created?".

Comment: Do you want to set the value of the variable to what the user inputs, or do you want to create a variable with the name that the user inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to create an environment variable with the name entered by the user of the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Loop
rem Define environment variable "input" with a double quote as default value.
rem This is necessary to avoid an execution break after user input because of
rem not defined "input" variable in case of user just hits RETURN or ENTER on
rem prompt without entering anything.
set "input=""
set /p "input=Input something here: "
rem Remove all double quotes, left and right angle brackets entered by the user.
set "input=%input:"=%"
set "input=%input:<=%"
set "input=%input:>=%"
rem Has the use entered anything at all?
if "%input%"=="" goto Loop
set "%input%=This variable name was entered by the user."
echo Your input has been stored in a variable.
set "%input%"
endlocal
```

But I do not recommend this. It is very dangerous as the user can enter characters with a special meaning resulting in batch exit because of a syntax error or even more worse a manipulation of batch execution.

For example if the batch user enters a string starting with an equal sign, this code as is would result in a syntax error on further processing. Critical is also a string entered by the user which is the name of an important predefined environment variable like **PATHEXT**, **PATH**, **APPDATA**, **USERNAME**, ...

I strongly recommend not do what you currently want to do. It would be interesting for us why you want to create an environment variable with a name entered by the user of the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe this will help.

```
@ECHO OFF   

:loop
set /p input=input something here: 
if %input%==. goto loop
if not %input%==. goto store_userinput_as_variable
:store_userinput_as_variable
cls

ECHO You entered: %input%

REM Create a variable with the same name as the value they entered.
CALL SET %input%=New Variable

CALL ECHO The variable "%input%" has a value of "%%%input%%%"
```

So if you enter "Hello", the output would be:

```
You entered: Hello
The variable "Hello" has a value of "New Variable"
```